# Prestashop 1.6 extend max size of product feature value

Tags: prestashop

This is my first question on stackoverflow :)
I need to import a csv file with product features values longer than 128 characters. How can I extend the maximum size of product features values  in prestashop 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature value field should be `255` characters long, unless you are using some special characters or different encoding.

Anyway,
change the column type in `ps_feature_value_lang` table to your preference,

Then make an override for `FeatureValue.php` class. Make a file at `override/classes/FeatureValue.php` and inside this file:

```
class FeatureValue extends FeatureValueCore
{
    /**
 * @see ObjectModel::$definition
 */
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'feature_value',
    'primary' => 'id_feature_value',
    'multilang' => true,
    'fields' => array(
        'id_feature' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        'custom' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),

        // Lang fields
        'value' =>      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
    ),
);
}
```

Modify `'size' => 255` to match the db column.

Comment: It works! I had to delete class_index.php in cache/ to make the override of the class works. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention it, I hope it didnt take long :(