# How to extend feature value length in PrestaShop 1.6.1.6?

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.6

When I enter a value longer than 255 characters in a feature value, I get an error stating "The name for feature  is too long in ."

I've created an override and increased the size of the DB field such as gskema suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902159/prestashop-1-6-extend-max-size-of-product-feature-value) and deleted class_index in /cache with no effect. The override doesn't seem to work.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: is the error (I didn't provided full error message) pointed on your new "child" class now?

Comment: @SergiiP: Not sure I understand your question.
I used placeholders in the error message, which were removed. Here's the full error message: "The name for feature Ingredients is too long in Italiano (Italian)."
The same error happens now that I've overridden the class.

Comment: try to do next, in config/defines.inc.php set *define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);* (you can find in first lines of the file), then in the debug error message do you see point to new class? Also I guess you changed *'size' => 255* in gskema solution to match the DB field size

Comment: Debug messages don't show up. I've cleared the cache, both in the BO and by deleting files in /web/cache/smarty/compile & /web/cache/smarty/cache.
Yes, I've changed the DB field size to the same value as in FeatureValue.php.

Comment: so, to be clear, you have DB field size e.g. 512 and in new class that you created size 512 and it doesn't work, right?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it!
I wonder whether it could have to do with misplacing or misnaming the file. I followed gskema's solution EXACTLY, case and all.

Comment: Does anyone have another clue to help me out? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I see only one possibility - you did something wrong. If you did all thing exactly, placed the class file, changed the table ps_feature_value_lang value filed to varchar(512) and deleted class_index file - it should works. Also full error message on my side looks like "The field value (English (English)) is too long (255 chars max, html chars including)." with field length explanation.

Comment: I really wish it would; believe me! ;o) I've checked it all: site_root/override/classes/FeatureValue.php contains a copy of the solution source (except for field size, which I adjusted. I've changed the permissions to 644 (as they were 664), checked the DB field size and deleted site_root/cache/class_index.php. I still get "The name for feature Ingredients is too long in Italiano (Italian).". Choosing another language doesn't make any difference; not that it should...

Comment: I repeated all steps on my side, all works as expected. In your case, I think be better some debug, step by step, first check is overriden class works, etc.

Comment: I read your error message again, are you trying to create new feature and set feature name or add feature value to existing feature?

Comment: I'm adding a feature value to an existing custom feature. As to checking that the class is as expected, this is what I found in class_index.php:
`  'FeatureValue' => 
  array (
    'path' => '',
    'type' => 'class',
    'override' => false,
  ),
  'FeatureValueCore' => 
  array (
    'path' => 'classes/FeatureValue.php',
    'type' => 'class',
    'override' => false,
  ),
`

Comment: there must be *'path' => 'override/classes/FeatureValue.php'* for FeatureValue class

Comment: While I understand that should be in the class_index.php file, adding it there would be dangerous as the file is generated automatically. Therefore, where is the safe place to add this?

Comment: you do not need to add it, I just showed you that something wrong there, unfortunately I don't understand exact reason, as I said need to do some debug. Try to change *size* value directly in core class, check if it works, and then debug the override system

Comment: today on one of my client's website I faced with "strange" override system behavior in 1.6.1.6 core, so maybe your problem is version related, I'm still trying to find a reason, on your side try to delete class index manually few times, is this helps?

Comment: If I change the core class, things _seem_ to work (success message) but aren't written to the database. Deleting class_index.php multiple times unfortunately doesn't work either.
Changing class_index.php causes the "save" buttons to appear "loading" forever. When I go to the features tab, I see a "loading" circle arrow and it turns forever. [http://nemops.com/spinning-save-button-prestashop-1-6/#.V31U5DWQo7Q] points at a module not loading, among other causes. This seems to point at an error in the override class.
I look forward to reading your news about the resolution of your client's bug.

Comment: Actually I "resolved" the client issue, with deleting classes cache and can't repeat the bug again. Unfortunately I can't help you without access to codebase. If you did changes in the core it should works, you can try to use one of previous versions, core debug etc. I have no other ideas.

Comment: Thanks @SergiiP for your efforts! If you're willing, I could provide you with access to codebase via FTP and to PS BO so you can try this your way. I would very much appreciate it. I could provide credentials through Skype or other private communication means.

Comment: write me on gmail serg grey (without space between 2 words), I'll check it, I'm just interesting what really happening there on your side